# Not able to return a query inside a get function in DRF

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have to insert distance as an input parameter and work on this code. But I'm not able to return the query. When I run, the program is asking for distance.

```
{
    "distance": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from Admin_Section.models import Distance

class ServiceProviderList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class=ProfilecompletioneSerializer
    filterset_class=SnippetFilter
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['fullname', 'category','departments','services']
    search_fields = ['fullname', 'category__name','departments__dept_name','services__service_name']

    def get_queryset(self,*args, **kwargs): 
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        qs = CustomerProfile.objects.filter(user=pk)
        if qs.exists():
            customer = qs.first()
        else:
            return qs.none()
    def get(self,request,*args, **kwargs): 
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=pk)
        serializer = DistanceSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        Dist = serializer.validated_data['distance']
        print(Dist)
        rad=float(Dist)
        radius=rad/111
        print(radius)
        query = ProfileCompletion.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(customer.location,radius))
        return query
```

Comment: you add `Distance` as a fifth parameters in the `get` function

Comment: Can you please explain it? I'm new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to send payload in the `GET` request body. Your question is not very clear, but looking at the code, if you want to use the `distance` to filter data in queryset, you should use query parameters. You can send the query params in the URL using `some-url?distance=10` from the client and these can be read in the view using `request.query_params` which will be a `dict` of query parameters.

Comment: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

Comment: @suryaraj you are returning `query` from the view, you need to serialize it first, and then return `Response(data=serializer.data)`